# jQuery: tabs with URL without 'page jump'

Tags: jquery

I have a set of tabs and I need to be able to have each tab's URL display the correct/active tab if someone pastes it in the address bar.

Script:

```
$(function() { 
    $('.tabs span').click(function(){
        switch_tabs($(this));
        return false;
    }); 
    switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));
});

function switch_tabs(obj) {
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tabs span').removeClass("selected");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");
    $('#'+id).show();
    obj.addClass("selected");
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#a"><span rel="a" class="defaulttab">A</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#b"><span rel="b">B</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#c"><span rel="c">C</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#d"><span rel="d">D</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#e"><span rel="e">E</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="a">content</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="b">content</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="c">content</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="d">content</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="e">content</div>
```

So if someone pastes "*http://www.domain.com/aboutus/page#c*" in their browser for example, the browser goes to that page and **tab C** is active BUT the page doesn't jump down.

Does this make sense?

Thanks a lot for any help on this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot avoid that, but you can work around by scrolling back to the top of the page using `window.scrollTo`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  if(location.hash) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}, 1);
```

Comment: Needs to be altered if there is actually an anchor on the page that I want to jump to.

Comment: @simshaun - I thought the OP wanted to be at the top of the page.

Comment: If the tabs are the only anchors on the page, then its fine.  Im just saying if there are other anchors on the page, then the script needs to be modified so it only scrolls to the top if the anchor points to one of the tabs.

Comment: Interesting, will keep it in my list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can change that.  AFAIK, the browser does the jump before JavaScript can stop it.  I guess I could be wrong though.

As an alternative, you could provide urls with a non-existing anchor name (e.g. "http://www.domain.com/aboutus/page#tab_c"). JavaScript would remove the tab_ portion and then display the appropriate tab.

Comment: Javascript can stop the jump, `e.preventDefault();` where `e` is the click event object would do it

Comment: Yes, you can do that when *clicking* on a link, but he's talking about if somebody puts the URL http://www.domain.com/page#c in the browser.

Comment: I need to provide a complete URL,but I can live with the page jumping down to the tab. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it here with my javascript: http://www.starcraft-source.com/tv/#stream-2

```
    //assuming `#tab1` is your hash, `tab1` will be shown
    if (parent.location.hash.length > 0) {
          showTab(parent.location.hash);
    }
```

It'd also require linking your tabs like `href="tab1"`

Here's how I use it...

```
Spire.Tv = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            if (parent.location.hash.length > 0) {
                this.loadStream(parent.location.hash.split('-')[1]);
            }

            $('.stream').bind('click', function (e) {
                Spire.Tv.loadStream($(e.currentTarget).attr('id'));
            });

            $('#rightbar-full a.stream').bind('click', function (e) {
                Spire.Tv.loadStream($(e.currentTarget).attr('id'));
            });
        },
        loadStream: function (id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: webRoot + "/lib/ajax/site/tv/getStream.php",
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#screen').html(data.screen);
                    parent.location.hash = 'stream-'+data.id;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}();
```

Notice how I"m controlling the hash on the page with: `parent.location.hash = 'stream-'+data.id;`

Comment: Yes, I see it working on your website, but your code is compressed so it's impossible to understand for me, I'm very new to this. Any idea where in my code should I put that if? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is the closest to my solution but it doesn't solve my problem entirely since your implementation is so different than mine. I gave you a vote though. Thanks.

Comment: Can you update your initial post with your most recent code and what's left to be accomplished?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a name for the anchor:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_bookmark

```
Something like <a name="C4">Chapter 4</a>
```

Based on your code:

```
<li><a href="#c" name="c"><span rel="c">C</span></a></li>
```

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. Thanks for pointing it out though Ives.